What is a crystal system, compared to a Bravais lattice?
In my condensed matter class I have been told there are 7 crystal systems: Triclinic, Monoclinic, Orthorhombic, Tetragonal, Trigonal, Hexagonal, Cubic.
I am also told there are 14 Bravais lattices. I think I understand this statement, this is sismply saying "there are 14 different lattices in 3D up to isomoprhism of the lattice symmetry group".
What does it mean for there to be 7 crystal systems? What defines a crystal system? Is the crystal system classification a property of the lattice, or of the crystal (lattice + basis)? Is this classification arbitrary (i.e. simply defined in terms of which Bravais lattices fit into each crystal system), or is there more?

See https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35273/why-are-there-only-7-types-of-unit-cells-and-14-types-of-bravais-lattices/35277#35277 for example.

@JonCuster it is good post, but my understanding is not cleared up by the description: "A physical crystal can be described by giving its underlying Bravais lattice, together with a description of the arrangement of atoms, molecules, ions, etc. within a particular primitive cell". I do not formally understand what a crystal system is? How is it rigorously defined? I do not see where "7" comes out of...

There is a long article on Wikipedia explaining in detail the relation between Bravais lattices and crystal systems, etc.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_system
